# Can you trace a .onion address?

Tags: tor, onion-routing

How can I get the IP address for a Tor Hidden Service (HS) with a .onion address?

Comment: Basically the same as with any domain.
If you need to learn how that works I would suggest asking the question on Stack Exchange since its off-topic for security.

Comment: You can't. If you have access to most routers on the Internet, then you might be able.

Comment: @LvB It is on-topic, but is a duplicate. A .onion address is an anonymous domain accessible via the Tor anonymity network. Deanonymization attacks are certainly on-topic.

Comment: @forest I agree that Deanonymization attacks are on topic. it is just not (clear) that James is Asking that. what he is asking is answered indeed (is should have done a search before giving a quick comment)